# How to load 2 controllers from different codeigniters?

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, authentication, controllers

I'm trying to access the controller from another CodeIgniter.
I have a CodeIgniter 3.0.4 that containing:

- Application
- codeigniter2
- css
- js
- ...

so I have already tried `$this->load->library('../controllers/home');` ,

but it shows me the Unable to load the requested class: Home

And I'm trying to login to both at the same time so I need to access each Session

Comment: It is not the MVC way but you might need to look at using HMVC https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc you cannot do what you have done with library The HMVC only works with CI3 versions

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly suggest that you simply either import the required library or combine both apps into the latest CI 3.1 as there have been several security fixes plus many more bug fixes. Upgrading from 2.x to 3.x is usually a very simple task.

However, you will not be able to use the CI loader to load a controller or library outside the normal directories, and you will not be able to share sessions across them either, as both sessions will have a different format for their session tables.

At a push, you might be able to create a bridge library, that includes the files you want, from the older CI version, but to be honest, unless the libraries you are connecting to are completely empty of any CI references, more like functional helpers rather than libraries, it just is not going to work, or would take far more work to achieve that it would to just upgrade and combine your old system. The advantages of doing that far outweigh the problems you are going to face with a bridging mechanism.

Sorry if that is not a lot of help, but in short, combine them into one app and upgrade to the latest version ASAP.

Best wishes,

Paul.